# How to create icon overlay?

Tags: vb.net

I tried this howto: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545781/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Icon-Overlay-Handlers

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports SharpShell.Interop
<ComVisible(True)>
Public Class IconOverlayYeah : Inherits SharpShell.SharpIconOverlayHandler.SharpIconOverlayHandler

    Protected Overrides Function CanShowOverlay(path As String, attributes As FILE_ATTRIBUTE) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function


    Protected Overrides Function GetOverlayIcon() As System.Drawing.Icon
        Return New System.Drawing.Icon("C:\Users\user\Desktop\icon.ico")
    End Function


    Protected Overrides Function GetPriority() As Integer
        Return 90
    End Function
End Class
```

Registered resulting dll with regasm.exe (visible with regedit.exe) but unfortunately my icon does not show up in explorer or anywhere. I have only 6 overlays registered and tried a lot of workaround I found via google. But I can not get it to work. Can you please help me?

Comment: Apart from the usual 32/64 bit issues, I doubt that accessing the icons from a user profile works. Try adding them to the project's resources and return them from your resources.

Comment: thx! Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

The regasm.exe will only register the assembly. But according to [How to Register Icon Overlay Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127455(v=vs.85).aspx),

> In addition to normal Component Object Model (COM) registration, the following 
>   steps must be completed in order to register icon overlay handlers.
>   Step 1: Create a subkey named for the handler under this key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>      Software
>        Microsoft
>            Windows
>              CurrentVersion
>                 Explorer
>                    ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
>   Step 2: Set the default value of the subkey to the string form of the object's > class identifier (CLSID)GUID

You can use srm.exe or ServerManager.exe from SharpShell(you can download these from [here](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell/releases).

Also, try restarting the explorer after you register the icon overlay handler.

Hope this helps.